# Yii2: safe validator on condition

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I am trying to use this validation rule in my model, but it's not working.

I mean it always remains safe even if select other option.

```php
[['dhanwantri_bill_number'], 'safe', 
    'when' => function($model) {
        return $model->bill_type =='d';                 
    },
    'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                         return $('#opdtestbill-bill_type').val() == 'd';
                     }"
],
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
is there any alternative solution to achieve the same.

Thanks.

Rule for `bill_type` is like

```
[['bill_type'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
[['bill_type','test_name','date'], 'required'],
```

**Edit**
safe attribute public properties as per doc

> $when -   callable -  A PHP callable whose return value determines
>   whether this validator should be applied.     yii\validators\Validator
>
> $whenClient -     string -    A JavaScript function name whose return value
>   determines whether this validator should be applied on the client
>   side.     yii\validators\Validator

Comment: Do you have any other rules for this attribute?

Comment: Do you really want to use the 'safe' validator? [Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-safevalidator.html) says _SafeValidator serves as a dummy validator whose main purpose is to mark the attributes to be safe for massive assignment._ So you want to disallow the assignment of dhanwantri_bill_number if bill_type is 'd'?

Comment: @robsch - No it's exactly the opposite - I want to allow the assignment if `dhanwantri_bill_number` if bill_type is 'd' and disallow in other cases.

Comment: @topherkanyuga - No I have no other rules for this attribute.

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought it...

Comment: Do you have a rule for bill_type?

Comment: Yes for '`bill_type` rule is there. updating the question with `bill_type` rule

Comment: have you tried to log the value of `$('#opdtestbill-bill_type').val()`?

Comment: @zazu - No, how to do that? however I have tried removing the quotes from the 'd', which generates the error undefined constant and the value posted in the error is correct like `opdtestbill-bill_type=>'d';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the 'safe' validator just tells that an attribute may be set by massive assignment, the approach is not appropiate. It just says that when you use the [load()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load%28%29-detail) method the attribute can get a value. And if not marked as 'safe' it doesn't prevent setting a value with e.g. `$model->dhanwantri_bill_number = 'asdf'`. So it is not a proper solution.

More precisely: the 'safe' attribute does not have an effect when `$model->validate()` (which is usually called with `$model->save()`) gets called. It is only used when `$model->load()` is called. If you look into the [source code of the SafeValidatior](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/SafeValidator.php) class you see that nothing happens with this validator. The validator doesn't do anything. It is just a marker (you may want to compare it to e.g. [RequiredValidator](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/RequiredValidator.php)). And with `load()` the 'when' expression is not used. So you can say **'safe' doesn't work with 'when'**. The safe validator may get used when the rule gets evaluated but its `validateAttribute()` is empty so nothing happens in that point in time.

Besides the `whenClient` in your code doesn't make sense. What should happen here?

I guess there are several ways of realizing that. One idea would be to let the controller set the attributes not by load(), rather set them explicitely and check there if `$model->dhanwantri_bill_number` should be set or not. Or you could use load() and then revert the attribute after loading according to what `$model->bill_type` is set.

Or you could implement a setter method for dhanwantri_bill_number in your model and choose there if the attribute gets set or not. Maybe scenario dependent.

Comment: but the doc says with `safe validator` these public properties are available as `callable` - I have added the properties in my question.

Comment: So 'safe' doesn't work with 'when', so should I assume that what is mentioned in the docs is not correct? as in the doc it is clearly mentioned that `when` is available with `safe`

Comment: @Pawan Yes, 'when' is there. But the safe validator has an effect only on load(). And on load the model just looks which attributes are part of the validation rules (all mentioned attributes (of the current scenario) without an '!' prefix). It does not evaluate the 'when' expression in that step. This happens when the validate() method of the model is called. And that is already to late. IMO the doc lacks with SafeValidator class.

Answer (score 1):

From Yii2 doc:

> By default, an active attribute is considered safe and can be massively assigned. If an attribute should NOT be massively assigned (thus considered unsafe), please prefix the attribute with an exclamation character (e.g. '!rank').

Consider to use scenarios to handle your problem.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios